# VS CodedUI fails to launch GUI for classic Windows Application

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, coded-ui-tests

I have a self hosted build agent setup to run interactively for the purposes of executing CodedUI in Azure DevOps for a classic Windows Application.  For some reason though I can't get the build server to actually run the application under test with a UI. I have tried starting my application in a variety of ways but regardless of the way in which I try to start the app no UI ever appears although the app does show up in the Task Manager so I know that it is running.

The tests execute fine on development machines but completely fail when they run on the server.  I feel like I am missing something with either the agent configuration or something in the build but I am missing it. I have re-configured the Agent 3 times to make sure I didn't overlook anything in the docs and I have gone through the Pipelines documentation regarding UI tests but it wasn't very useful.

Has anyone run into this issue before? I am happy to provide any additional information that might be useful in tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, although I am not entirely sure why this solution works while the others do not. Basically I created a class that represents my applications icon like so:

```
public class AppIcon : CodedUIBase
{
    public AppIcon()
    {
        SetParentName("Program Manager");
    }

    public WinListItem LstAppIcon
    {
        get { return SetProperty<WinListItem>(PropertyType.Name, "AppName"); }
    }
}
```

And then I start my application by clicking on this icon like so:

```
var appIcon = new AppIcon();
appIcon.LstAppIcon.DoubleClick();
```

This allows the UI to run just fine on the build server and tests execute just fine.  It feels odd that using `ApplicationUnderTest()` and `Process.Start()` cause the build server to load these into background processes but double clicking on the icon works just fine.

Comment: Test automation works in mysterious ways, glad that you figured it out. Keep at it :)